# How to force screen orientation at some ViewController on iPad Air2 iOS9.2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, screen, uiinterfaceorientation

At iOS8 i used

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

but not working at iOS9 iPad Air2, 
Also, I find another solution but not working either,
override the function below in custom UINavigationController:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.viewControllers.lastObject supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.viewControllers.lastObject preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return self.visibleViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You certainly had defined the allowed orientations in info.plist which overrides anything you do anywhere else throughout the project.

To correct the issue you can  removed the entries from info.plist and defined them in the project settings.

[image]

Comment: I removed them, but it appeared again after I redefined them in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

try this in viewDidAppear:

```
  NSNumber *orientationValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue: orientationValue forKey:@"orientation"];
```

it can be flicker in this answer. if you don't want flicker, try this option it will work:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if ([self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass: [SecondViewController class]])
{
    SecondViewController *secondController = (SecondViewController *) self.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```

Comment: Did you select other orientation from project settings

Comment: Do i need to remove them all?